# How to stop data insertion on refreshing the JSP page?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, post, page-refresh

This is my JSP file.

When I refresh the page, it will save the previous or null entries again into the database which is not good.

I only want to save the data when the save button is clicked.

Please help me to solve this.

**index.jsp:**

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="javax.swing.JOptionPane"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>

<form method="post">


            <h1>hello</h1>
            name<input type="text" name="name" required>
            class<input type="text" name="class">
            <button type="submit" onclick="btn()">save</button>

        </form>

 <script lang="javaScript">
     function btn(){
 <%

            String s1 = request.getParameter("name");
            String s2 = request.getParameter("class");
            try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            java.sql.Connection con;
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/school","root","password");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            int i = stmt.executeUpdate("insert into demo(name,class) values('"+s1+"','"+s2+"')");

            out.println("Data is successfully inserted");
            }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            out.println("fail");
            }
            %>
                }
</script>
            <%-- for dynamic table --%> 

<h2 align="center"><font><strong>Retrieve data from database in jsp</strong></font></h2>
<table align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
<tr>

</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#A52A2A">
<td><b>name</b></td>
<td><b>class</b></td>
</tr>
<%
    //Connection con = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
try{ 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            java.sql.Connection con;
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/school","root","password");
            stmt=con.createStatement();
String sql ="SELECT * FROM demo";

resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while(resultSet.next()){
%>
<tr bgcolor="#DEB887">

<td><%=resultSet.getString("name") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("class") %></td>

</tr>

<% 
}

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check this from java session. Put a flag in java session and submit based on the flag

```js
if (session.getAttribute("dataInserted") == null )
{
   //do the insertion process
   session.putAttribute("dataInserted","true");
} else {
   //if re-submission
}
```